# python + auto ssh proccess to get date info

Tags: python

I need to perform on my linux 5.3

```
   ssh [Linux machine red hat 5.3] date
```

in order to get the date results , during ssh need to answer on the following question

1. (yes/no)? -->    yes
2. password: -->    diana_123

and then I will get the date results

please advice how to do this automated process with python? ( on my Linux I have 
Python 2.2.3 )

python script should get the IP address number , and perform automatically ssh to 103.116.140.151 and return the date results

```
     as -->  Fri Nov 18 11:25:18 IST 2011
```

example of manual proccess:

```
  # ssh 103.116.140.151 date
    The authenticity of host '103.116.140.151 (103.116.140.151)' can't be established.
    RSA key fingerprint is ad:7e:df:9b:53:86:9f:98:17:70:2f:58:c2:5b:e2:e7.
    Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
    Warning: Permanently added '103.116.140.151' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
    root@10.116.10.151's password: 

    Fri Nov 18 11:25:18 IST 2011
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to just [configure passwordless logins](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/152). Basically, create a local ssh key pair with

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

and put the public key into `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys` at `103.116.140.151`. If you don't care about the key of the remote host, add the `-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no` ssh option.

Alternatively, use an SSH library such as [Paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/):

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
# Uncomment the following line for the equivalent of -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no
#ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('103.116.140.151', username='user', password='diana_123')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("date")
date = stdout.read()
print(date)
```

Comment: sorry I need python for this , I cant use keys because some resons

Comment: @david Ok, **added a Python solution**. Can you elaborate why keys are not an option? They're way more secure, especially if you intend to hardcode passwords in your Python code.

Comment: thx but how to run it on my linux machine only copy and passed thats all?

Comment: I get -->        File "./python", line 6 ssh = paramiko.SSHClient() ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @david Well, you need to install paramiko first. On a debian/Ubuntu machine, you can do `sudo apt-get install -y paramiko` to do that. Alternatively, checkout paramiko (Either with `git clone https://github.com/robey/paramiko.git` or by downloading https://github.com/robey/paramiko/zipball/master) and put the `paramiko` directory containing the Python files in your `sys.path`.

Comment: @david It's a very bad idea to call your python script `python`, as it may be confused with the interpreter. A SyntaxError means you have added spaces or unbalanced braces to the code by accident. If you want us to help you with that, post your whole code to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) so we can see where the spaces have been added.

Comment: Note that the `set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())` works great, but as an _alternative_ to `load_system_host_keys()` -- **not** both.  Trust me: it seems to work great until you rebuild a remote machine and the cached keys in `.ssh/known_hosts` are stale.

Answer (score 2):

You can skip the host key check by passing the StrictHostKeyChecking=no parameter to ssh:

```
ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no 103.116.140.151 date
```

I don't think it's possible to do the same for the password.  The correct way to bypass SSH's password prompt is with a restricted passphraseless key: see [here](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/152) for details.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use key based passwordless login, you can use [**expect**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) package on Linux. It gives answers you choose to questions.

You can use this package from python with [**pexpect**](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect).

Comment: sorry I not have expect in my linux and I cant to install it